# Non-Java programming language for Android 2.1

Tags: android, compiler

I'm looking for a programming language (+ compiler obviously):

- not Java;
- programs must run on Android 2.1 ("API version 7");
- open-source;
- "more concise than Java" - I know this is soft requirement and somewhat subjective, so let's say this is optional;

  - *(also here I'd prefer not brainfuck or other similarly "esoteric"; but e.g. Forth or something like that would be ok)*
- should produce not too big apps ("hello world" < 1MB);
- **must** be able to build full GUI (i.e. Activities etc.) without any Java stubs/... - not one line of Java;
- also, should really support multithreaded programming;
- should be stable.

For now I **tried Kawa**; looked very good initially, but I seem to encounter some exceptions I can't really understand why; generally after some time I feel there's too much fighting with the compiler for me.

[edit] **Tried [Mirah+"Pindah"](https://github.com/mirah/pindah)** too, but it seems to have got defunct somewhere between Java 6 and 7; when building sample project with *rake debug*, in Java 6 I get error: *"NameError: cannot link Java class mirah.impl.MirahParser, probable missing dependency: mirah/impl/MirahParser : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0"*, while in Java 7: *"taskdef class org.mirah.ant.Compile cannot be found"*.

[edit] According to one blog post, [Scala 2.11 is reportedly not compatible with Android API 8 and earlier](http://blog.scaloid.org/2014/04/android-api-8-is-incompatible-with.html), so I assume I can **rule out Scala** before even trying.

<sub>[edit] Pending research for the following:</sub>
<sub>[HolonJ Forth](http://holonforth.com/tools/java/holonj.htm) -- seems to [target JVM 1.2](http://holonforth.com/tools/java/usingholonj/usinghj.htm), so not sure if not too old;</sub>
<sub>[Bigloo Scheme](http://www-sop.inria.fr/indes/fp/Bigloo/bigloo-2.html) -- but Windows builds of the compiler seem to lag ~2 years, so I'd have to try building in MSYS;</sub>
<sub>...todo: [moar from the Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages): Ceylon? Joy? Fantom?...</sub>

Comment: Why can't you use Java?

Comment: What about using C++ in conjunction with the native development kit (NDK)?

Comment: @ComFreek AFAIK, with NDK I can't use GUI and I have to write a Java stub for each Activity, isn't that true? Also, I believe the NDK API is severely limited, no?

Comment: @Milo I can't force myself to continue working on certain project I started in Java. I want to try completing it, but I need some way to reduce frustration level.

Comment: @akavel It seems that you are indeed limited as long as you don't create a bridge to Java. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583713/android-build-native-gui-app-with-ndk#comment13706082_10583713 and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/396538/Writing-an-Android-GUI-using-Cplusplus-Introductio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Yeti](http://mth.github.io/yeti/)** is [ML style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_(programming_language)) functional programming language.

- I verified it builds for and runs on Android 2.1 emulator;
- [open-source, BSD-licensed](http://mth.github.io/yeti/);
- ML-family language, so I expect it to be more concise than Java;
- entire *yeti.jar* is ~570KB;
- can emit Java classes extending others (thus Android Activities too), so can build Android GUI;
- no idea about multithreading for now.

Comment: As of now, this *feels **fun!*** And, to my surprise, I feel like quietly *cheating* on Java... And it already helped me push the app forward, so it's only right to call Yeti the winner! at least for now.

Answer (score 0):

So, at the time of writing (09.2014), **[Kotlin](http://kotlinlang.org/)** seems a viable alternative.

- I verified it builds for and runs on Android 2.1 emulator;
- [open-source, Apache license v2.0](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/4e41673b75b2e078adb2e84e35364e5ee0d29652/license/LICENSE.txt);
- seems somewhat "more concise than Java", however slightly on first look;
- [simple two-activity hello-world-like apk](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/tree/5fd2cbf2903f9bbeef8357cd367127e34f15866d/gradle/android-mixed-java-kotlin-project) in debug mode is at ~600kb;
- haven't verified multithreading yet, but I expect it's there.